# Divide all cells in column A by last cell in column A and repeat for columns B-L

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet of numbers from A1 to L10. I need to divide cells A2-A9 by the last number in the column (A10). I need the result of those calculations to go into column N (N1-N8). Then I need to repeat that for column B - divide B2-B9 by B10 and put the result of those calculations into column O (O1-O8). This needs to repeat for columns C-L putting the result of the calculations into columns P-Y. I have the code to divide A2-A9 by A10, but I cannot figure out how to repeat this for the rest of the columns.

```
Sub Divide_a_range_by_last_number()

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 to 9
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i,14).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i,1).Value / (Range("A1").End(xlDown))

Next i
End Sub
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you set on using VBA? Seems you could input `=A2/A$10` into N1 and then drag the formula down to N8 and across to column Y

Comment: yes, want to use VBA because this is only a part of a larger code

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need one more level of iteration, to repeat the divide process for columns A through L. You could accomplish this using another for-loop - to iterate through each column, and call your "divide" function each time. You'll just need to update your divide function to accept the current column number to operate on:

```
' Iterate through columns A-L.
For j = 1 to 12
    ' Provide the current column that you want the divide function to operate on.
    Call Divide_a_range_by_last_number(i)
Next

' Update the function signature to accept the current column number.
Sub Divide_a_range_by_last_number(curColumn as Long)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 to 9
        ' Update this line to use curColumn variable, instead of static column numbers (i.e. 1 and 14).
        Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i,curColumn + 13).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i,curColumn).Value / Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(10,curColumn).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

I'm pretty new to VBA, so the syntax may not be perfect. But, this should get you started.